# How to update particular record using update query in SQL Server with vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the query to retrieve selected record in textbox ./..

How to use this query to update record :

I want when I enter sumit in textbox1 and click submit button then the record with ID 1 will be updated to name sumit///

```
Dim SQLData As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM Table1 Order by Id DESC", SQLData)
SQLData.Open()
Dim dtrReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
If dtrReader.HasRows Then
   While dtrReader.Read()
      TextBox1.Text = dtrReader("Name")
   End While
Else
   Response.Write("No customer found for the supplied ID.")
End If

dtrReader.Close()
SQLData.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a SqlCommand with a CommmandText like this

```
UPDATE FOO SET CustomerName = @CustomerName WHERE ID = @ID
```

then add two parameters to your commmand with values capture from inputs and run it after setting connection and opening it.

Take a look at this [page](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) and it will help you through your work done

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!